# SSD Backup Restore

Tags: ssd, backup, restore, windows-backup

I recently repaired my pc and took a backup of the boot SSD to be safe. I had to uninstall some programs to get the pc working again so files have been removed from the SSD. Now I need to restore the backup but I know I can't wipe the SSD as it's the boot drive and there are way too many files to manually check for duplicates. 
Any help? 
Thanks

Comment: why dont you boot from a live usb and then restore the backup?

Comment: Just use System Image Recovery Tool, as @harrymc mentioned before. Just choose the image you created, and there's no need to check the files for duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore a system image from the boot recovery menu :

hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click the "Restart" option in the Start menu or Start screen.

The computer will boot to the special recovery menu. Click the “Troubleshoot” tile, click “Advanced Options,” and then click “System Image Recovery”.

[image]

If asked, choose a keyboard layout and then select the “Restore your computer using a system image that you created earlier” option in the System Recovery Options window. Select a system image from the backup drive and go through the rest of the wizard to restore it.